# Identify a book about founding of Scientology where female protagonist has sheep DNA and is an intended sacrifice

Tags: story-identification, books, religion

Identify a book about founding of Scientology where female protagonist has sheep DNA and is an intended sacrifice.

Answer (score 16):

[*The Android's Dream*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Android%27s_Dream) by [John Scalzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Scalzi).

The religion isn't Scientology (although it may have provided some inspiration). It's the Church of the Evolved Lamb, which started out as an explicit, avowed joke and became a real religion (whose member work actively to fulfill the founder's prophecies).

Comment: You beat me to it by a minute or so! (+1)

Comment: I read the title of this question and thought, "That sounds bizarre. I wonder if Scalzi had anything to do with it..."